# How can I delete the word `Category:` from page titles?

Tags: customization, css, templates

If I installed a new WordPress with twentysixteen theme and went to uncategorized page, I will see at the title something like

```
Category: Uncategorized
```

how can I remove the **category:** word from pages titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieve this title you need to extend [get_the_archive_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) . here is how or check the official [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/)

```
function wpse64458_get_the_archive_title($title){
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'wpse64458_get_the_archive_title');
```

Comment: it actually works! is there a way to modify it through theme template files not WordPress core files? because if i update my WordPress version everything been modified in WordPress core files will be overwritten by the update

Comment: where did you put those code ? you have to put this code I share into your themes file like functions.php then how it will be problem if you are update WordPress core? that filter provided WordPress to us to do this kind of modification. hope it make sense

Comment: i put the code inside wp-includes/general-template.php not in functions.php template file, sorry i am not good with codes and new to these stuff but i will try to add the code to functions.php

Comment: please do in your themes file and don't ever edit core file their are not meant for to edit or modified :)

Comment: yes it's now in functions.php theme file instead of wp-includes/general-template.php and it works :) thank you